# How do I read in a symbol in my data set as a blank?

Tags: r, dataset

In my dataset the symbol "." is used for a blank cell.
How can I manipulate the following code to make R treat the "." as blank?

File <- read.csv("C:\MyFile.CSV", header=T)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If by "blank" you mean `NA`, use the `na.strings` parameter.

Comment: Would i then use File <- read.csv("C:\MyFile.CSV", header=T, na.strings = ".") ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the right separator, `sep='.'`:

```
read.table(text='a.b.c
                a.b.c',sep='.')
 V1 V2 V3
1  a  b  c
2  a  b  c
```

**EDIT**
As mentioned by @Roland, the OP means by "blank" missings values, so here you should set `na.strings` parameter :

```
read.table(text='a b c .
                 a b c D',sep='',na ='.')

  V1 V2 V3   V4
1  a  b  c <NA>
2  a  b  c    D
```

Comment: When I try File <- read.csv("C:\MyFile.CSV", header=T, sep='.') it does not work? Or am I missing something?